# Google OR-Tools 7 on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, or-tools

Is it possible to install OR_Tools 7 on Eclipse?

or do I have to use Visual Studio 2017?

If so, how do I install it?

I have found only 6.7 version jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can found pre build binaries on the release page of the project:
https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases

If you download the archive `.zip` or `.tar.gz` depending on your platform you'll find in the lib directory the `com.google.ortools.jar` file (and the protobuf.jar too)

Note: Java OR-Tools is a wrapper on the C++ library i.e. it is a **native** library.

While the internal lib is compiled with the visual Studio 2019 compiler (and Java 8 IIRC), I guess you can use it (i.e. import it) inside an Eclipse project.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the dll file into java path and it works, thank you!